# ML deployment in Heroku

Tags: github, heroku, deployment

Iam doing a deployment in Heroku but failed as below log. Any advise would be appreciated.

```
*Procfile was added:web: gunicorn app:app
*requirements witouth versions
*runtime: python==3.9.13 
*flight_rf.pkl is a 560+mb (model info) file in github (should I trim the model file or just the config issue,hmm)



2022-10-24T10:56:06.842035+00:00 app[web.1]:     model = pickle.load(open("flight_rf.pkl","rb"))
2022-10-24T10:56:06.842035+00:00 app[web.1]: _pickle.UnpicklingError: invalid load key, 'v'.
2022-10-24T10:56:06.842315+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-10-24 10:56:06 +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
2022-10-24T10:56:07.538013+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-10-24 10:56:07 +0000] [4] [WARNING] Worker with pid 9 was terminated due to signal 15
2022-10-24T10:56:07.621643+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-10-24 10:56:07 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2022-10-24T10:56:07.621731+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-10-24 10:56:07 +0000] [4] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
2022-10-24T10:56:07.791193+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 3
2022-10-24T10:56:07.880199+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2022-10-24T10:56:31.496146+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=nzairfare.herokuapp.com request_id=09c72ff6-67d7-47de-a02a-57173824b6ed fwd="121.75.218.134" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-10-24T10:56:31.879287+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=nzairfare.herokuapp.com request_id=efd809eb-b825-4af3-9530-6a75a28f0a17 fwd="121.75.218.134" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Thank you!

Comment: Pickle files are specific to the version of Python you are using. Where did that file come from? Did you create it using the same version of Python you're using on Heroku?

Comment: Local conda env & heroku python under same version of 3.9.13